# If $A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$, find the rank of $A+A^2+A^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

**If $A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$, find the rank of $A+A^2+A^3$**

We have $\rho(A+A^2+A^3)\leq\rho(A)+\rho(A^2)+\rho(A^3) $ where $\rho(A)$ means rank of A.

Here $\rho(A)=3.$ Also $\rho(A^2)=3$ and $\rho(A^3)=3$  as $\det A\neq 0$ and $\det(A^2)=\det(A)\det(A)\neq 0$ and so on.

But how to get the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A(e_1) = e_3, A(e_2) = e_1, A(e_3) = e_2$. Thus $(A+A^2+A^3)(e_1) = e_3+e_2+e_1$, $(A+A^2+A^3)(e_2) = e_1+e_3+e_2$ and $(A+A^2+A^3)(e_3) = e_2+e_1+e_3$. Thus $A+A^2+A^3$ has rank 1.

Comment: @Murlidharan Please provide the meaning of $e_i$ and $A(e_i)$. would you write in more expanded form.

Comment: @user1942348 $e_1 = (1, 0, 0), e_2 =(0,1, 0), e_3 =(0,0,1)$

Comment: Ok. But how $(A+A^2+A^3)(e_i) = e_3+e_2+e_1$ implies $\rho(A+A^2+A^3)=1$

Comment: The space spanned by the column vectors of $(A+A^2 +A^3)$ is same as the span of the vector $e_1+e_2+e_3$. Rank of a matrix is the dimension of the space spanned by the column vectors of the matrix.

Comment: @user1942348 Just an elaboration of what mrka has replied: If $B=A+A^2+A^3$, then we have for any three scalars, $x,y,z$, $B(xe_1+ye_2+ze_3) = (x+y+z)(e_1+e_2+e_3)$ and hence the range of $B$ is one dimensional. Thus, rank of $B$ is 1.

Answer (score 4):

$A$ is a permutation matrix, meaning $A^2$ and $A^3$ are also permutation matrices. This gives you an easy way to find $A+A^2+A^3$ and from there, it's easily seen that rank is $1$.

**EDIT** To elaborate, a permutation matrix $P$ is a matrix that *acts* upon another matrix by permuting it's rows. Permutation matrix is just an identity matrix with permuted rows (In your case, $A$ is an identity matrix with second row shifted up, first row shifted 2 positions down and third row in the "middle"). This means that when you multiply $B$ by $A$ from the left, it will just reorder rows of $B$  ( same order as they are replaced in $A$ with respect to identity matrix ).

In your case, you multiply $A$ by this permutation matrix, meaning you will just get $A$ with permuted rows. This means that:

$$A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 0 & 1  \\
    1       & 0 & 0  \\
    0       & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: If A is a permutation matrix, then how $A^2$ and $A^3$ are also permutation matrices? Please explain. Also how it implies $\rho(A+A^2+A^3)=1$

Comment: @user1942348 I've edited the question to elaborate my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about inequalities. Just compute $A+A^2+A^3$, then consider the rank of the resulting matrix.

Comment: Finding $B=A+A^2+A^3$ one can find $\rho(B)$. But I need an alternating approach using properties.